# Qué código me sirve para poder usar dos veces un evento dentro de un botón con un solo click

Tags: java, android, firebase

Necesito que el evento se genere dos veces con dar un solo click en el boton guardar... Cómo podría ser el código para hacer esto?

Este es el código que quiero usar dos veces con un solo click al boton guardar.

```
guardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                DatabaseReference fbDb = database.getReference();

                if (fbDb == null) {
                    fbDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                }

                fbDb.child("numero")
                        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                // get total available quest
                                count = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();

                                DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("numero");
                                DatabaseReference currentUserDB = mDatabase.child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

                                String user_id = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

                                currentUserDB.child("num").setValue(count);

                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });

            }
        });
```

Comment: Puedes crear un método y llamarlo dos veces dentro del onClick. De todas formas el código que tienes de firebase debería ir fuera del click del botón y no estás haciendo ningún tipo de guardado con ese código.

Answer (score 1):

Como dicen arriba, tendrías que llamar dos veces el evento, para no repetir código te conviene poner todo dentro de una función, y llamar dos veces a dicha función:

```
private void hacerEnClick() {
  FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
  DatabaseReference fbDb = database.getReference();

  if (fbDb == null) {
    fbDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
  }

  fbDb.child("numero").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      // get total available quest
      count = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();

      DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("numero");
      DatabaseReference currentUserDB = mDatabase.child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

      String user_id = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

      currentUserDB.child("num").setValue(count);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
  });
}

guardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    //ACÁ LLAMAS DOS VECES LA FUNCIÓN hacerEnClick
    this.hacerEnClick();
    this.hacerEnClick();
  }
});
```

algo así debería quedar, no se si funcione directamente copiando y pegando.